# Birt reports not working in Internet Explorer 9 (IE 9)

Tags: java, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, birt

I have created and am running some birt reports in a java application using birt 3.7.2,
which are called from a jsp page like the followingL

```
birt:viewer id="birtViewer" reportDesign="reportName" pattern="frameset" showTitle="false" height="450" width="1058" format="html" scrolling="no" showParameterPage="false">
</birt:viewer>
```

These reports are working fine in all browsers except in IE 9. (working in IE 8 well).

I have to use BIRT in IE9 without adding meta compatible tag, as we're using metro UI, so the following :

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" >.
```

We can not use the meta tag because we are using metro UI there which is not compatible with IE 8.

Comment: what error does it occur? blank screen? error message?

Answer (score 0):

Check HTTP requests to confirm that you have percent encoded characters in you HTTP requests. 
IE9 has a problem with percent encoded characters in URL.

[KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/941052) explaining it is by design.

[Blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2006/12/06/file-uris-in-windows.aspx) explaining how does URI mechanism work at older Windows platform.

I wasn't able to find a solution for it. I had option to not to use encoding of URL requests to BIRT. I bypassed problem converting characters which needed encoding in something I understand and then replacing those converted character in BIRT script to its original value.

Comment: I am not able to understand. Can you please explain in brief what i have to do.

Comment: ravinder, you owe me a detailed description of your problem. My answer is to be considered if your problem is percent encoded characters in URL with which you invoke report. What is your problem then?